# Which rights are necessary to remove other people flags in patchset?

Tags: permissions, gerrit

I have a case when someone rates my patchset with flag `Code-review -2` and for some reason this person is unavailable but vote -2 blocks patchset from beeing submitted. I know admin can delete other people's flags from review.

My question is: which rights are sufficient to remove other people's votes in patchset? (Administrators, Project Owners, or any group with proper settings?)

Together with answer I would appreciate link to proper docs paragraph, if this is just a matter of some setting then which setting could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Remove Reviewer" privilege allows you to remove any reviewer from a patch. Moreover, to quote [the documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_remove_reviewer):

> Project owners and site administrators can always remove any reviewer (even without having the Remove Reviewer access right assigned).